# Doxygen 1.8 on Travis-ci

Tags: doxygen, travis-ci

I'm trying to generate doxygen docs on travis-ci, and got a `.travis.yml` file where i have before script like this:

```
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get install doxygen
```

I would expect to have the latest doxygen installed after this (1.8.x), but when i look in the build log i can see the following under `sudo apt-get install doxygen`:

```
...

Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main doxygen amd64 1.7.6.1-2ubuntu1 [2,427 kB]

...

Selecting previously unselected package doxygen.
Unpacking doxygen (from .../doxygen_1.7.6.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...

...
```

I'm not an ubuntu person myself, and don't know very much about apt-get, but when i look around it seems like the combination of `apt-get update`and apt-get install` should install the latest version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution

I had to add the libreoffice repository to apt-get. This is how the .travis.yml file looks like:

```
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 
    - sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-2
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get install doxygen
```